# how to watermark mp4 video with ffmpeg php

Tags: php

I need to watermark a mp4 video , Currently i am using this code, but it is not working , please solve this

```
<? exec('ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex overlay output.mp4');?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the filter code within double quotes. If you could share more about the error you're facing, I'll be able to help you better.

```
<? exec('ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay" output.mp4');?>
```

Comment: working bro......thankew....but i want know that , after video is watermark , why its is decreased?

Comment: How is it decreased? Could you share a snapshot maybe?